# STS getting this while pull/fetch latest changes Couldn't lock local tracking ref for update

Tags: egit, spring-tool-suite, sts

Getting this issue in spring tool suit while fetching/pull latest changes from remote branch. i don't have git bash on my local previously it was working fine right now i am getting below mention issue.

Couldn't lock local tracking ref for update

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered same problem
[image: lock fail Error After pulling from STS]
But I removed this problem using [GITHUB Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) tool.
Once I executed pull from STS, its showed the dialog box with error as shown above. and a up arrow got appended showing there are some commit to be pushed,
[image]
though I had not made any commits before this pull. The changes from pull were not added to my local project.

I checked on Github Desktop, and it also showed same arrow.

[image]

I pushed it from tool, and it was resolved. The changes from pull got added to local project.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't have git bash, Eclipse is using its own [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) (java-based implementation of Git)

As recommended in "[egit lock fail eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49859734/6309)", do check if you have any "`<refname>.lock`" file under `.git/refs/`". ([howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) refers to [eclipse issue 417860](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417860#c3):

> I checked in jgit and egit sources and found that the only occurrence of the text "`[lock fail]`" is used when fetch fails to update a remote tracking branch.
> This can happen if a previous crash didn't cleanup a "`<refname>.lock`" file which git creates as a lock to guard the ref against concurrent updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote prune origin
```

solved same problem for me